# PyQt implementing dialog icons

Tags: pyqt, pyside, maya

Every OS has their own implementation of a file browser and, in PyQt, using QFileDialog will always show that OS's version.

Some applications even have their own implementations of these windows and have their own back/forward/up button icons for those dialogs. Here are a couple examples:

The Foundry Mari

[image: QFileDialog from the program The Foundry Mari]

Autodesk Maya

[image: QFileDialog from the program, Autodesk Maya]

Both windows come up from the same code,

```
from PySide import QtGui
QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(QtGui.QWidget(), "Select Directory"))
```

I'm assuming this is either because of a stylesheet that's being applied by the software (in this case, Maya or Mari) or some other implementation but the point is, I'm making an application where I'd like to utilize the same method. That way, no matter what application a user calls my GUI in, it'll always kind of look like what they're used to seeing in that particular software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the global style icons (usually inherited from the system, unless it's been changed) using [`QStyle.standardIcon`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstyle.html#standardIcon)

```
style = QApplication.instance().style()
icon = style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_BrowserReload)
```

There is also [`QIcon.fromTheme`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qicon.html#fromTheme), but that currently only works on linux.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Marking as correct because this is a cross-application solution that suited my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse all available icon resources included with Autodesk Maya using the following 2017/Qt5 compatible code, which generates a basic search/filter dialog:

```
import maya.app.general.resourceBrowser as resourceBrowser
resBrowser = resourceBrowser.resourceBrowser()
resource_path = resBrowser.run()
print(path)  # SP_ComputerIcon.png
```

The resulting `SP_ComputerIcon.png` is the same icon pictured above in your Autodesk Maya dialog shot.

You can use any of the included resources once you know the image resource path as such:

```
# NOTE: Maya 2017 defaults to PySide2/Qt5, this won't work in 2016 or earlier
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets

testWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
testWindow.resize(100,100)

resource_path = 'SP_ComputerIcon.png'  # grabbed using preceding code    
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(':/{}'.format(resource_path))
icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
button.setIcon(icon)

testWindow.setCentralWidget(button)
testWindow.show()
```

Credit: [original source](http://mayaui.blogspot.com/2015/03/the-maya-factory-icon-browser.html)